# Turtle draw progam with user input: window vanishes. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a shape that requires user input for one of my variables and I am confused on how to get size1 to equal x and make my user input work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import turtle
import math


def drawSquareFromCenter(turtle, x): ...


    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(-x / 2)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(x / 2)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(x)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(x)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(x)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(x)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(x / 2)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(x / 2)
    turtle.right(90)


def main():
    # Create turtle
    bob = turtle.Turtle()

    # Get user input
    size1 = int(input('Enter size fore top square'))
    size2 = size1 * 2
    size3 = size1 * 3
    size4 = size1 * 4

    # Draw graphics
    bob.forward(size4 / 2)
    bob.right(90)
    bob.forward(-1 * (size4 + size3 + size2 + (size1 / 2)))
    drawSquareFromCenter(bob, size1)

    bob.forward((size1 + size2) / 2)
    drawSquareFromCenter(bob, size2)

    bob.forward((size2 + size3) / 2)
    drawSquareFromCenter(bob, size3)

    bob.forward((size3 + size4) / 2)
    drawSquareFromCenter(bob, size4)

    bob.right(45)
    bob.forward(math.sqrt(size4 / 2) ** 2 + (size4 / 2) ** 2)
    # Press any key to exit
    input()


main()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Which variable does not have the correct value? What value do you get and which did you expect?

Comment: Every time I run the code the turtle just shows for a split second. I am trying to connect the variables x and size1 together so that when it goes to create the shape it calculates in the drawSquareFromCenter function because size1 determines the size of the squares throughout the project. If there is a way for me to do that without having to possibly rewrite anything then that'd be nice.I feel that if I can connect both variables it should work, but I am not sure how. I feel like the answer is really simple, but I am just not seeing it

Comment: I tried to see if an if statement would work, but it did not seem to. Unless I did it wrong

Comment: Yes, the project is called layerCake and should start for after input but the window does not show up long enough for that. As soon as I hit run the window closes

Comment: Call `turtle.mainloop()` instead of `input()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console input window is probably hiding behind the turtle-draw window.

Ask for size first, then do the plotting to avoid the turtle-surface hiding your console window.

When plotting:

- penup + walk half the sides length in your facing direction + pendown
- rotate 90, draw half side,
- 3 times:

  - rotate 90, draw a side
- rotate 90, draw the missing half side
- rotate 90 + walk half a sides length back into center
- rotate 180 to face as when started

could be done like this:

```
import math
import turtle

def squareFromCurrPosAndRotationAsCenter(bob, s):
    """Starting from current position and rotation, draw a square of sidelength s.
    End on same position and rotation you began with."""
    # goto first side
    bob.penup()
    bob.forward(s/2)
    bob.pendown()
    # draw a half side
    bob.right(90)
    bob.forward(s/2)
    # draw three full sides
    for k in range(3):
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(s)
    # draw last half side
    bob.right(90)
    bob.forward(s/2)

    # goto back to origin
    bob.penup()
    bob.right(90)
    bob.forward(s/2)
    # turn back in original direction
    bob.right(180) 

def getInt(text, default):
    """Try to parse input to int, return default if not possible"""
    try:
        return int(input(text))
    except:
        return default
```

Main function:

```
def main():

    # Get user input or (when error) use default
    size        = getInt('Enter size for top square: ', 50)
    num_squares = getInt('Enter the amount of squares: ', 4)
    angle       = getInt('Enter increase of starting angle: ', 60)

    # Create turtle
    bob = turtle.Turtle()

    # adjust speed based on workload
    bob.speed(max(5,(num_squares * 360/angle)//10)) 

    # outer loop changes starting angle
    for startAngle in range(0,360-angle+1,angle):
        bob.setheading(startAngle)


        # we use a list comp to create the desired square sizes
        # you could also do [size, size*2, size*3, size*4] if 
        # you want always 4 circles

        for s in [size*(n+1) for n in range(num_squares)]:
            squareFromCurrPosAndRotationAsCenter(bob, s)

    turtle.mainloop()

main()
```

[image: layered squares with different starting angles]